# CSS - Creating advanced shapes. (Inverted Triangle?)

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a message bubble that looks similar to this:

[image]

However, all I can manage is this:

[image]

Using this CSS:

```
#messaging #test:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 120px;
  width: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  border-width: 32px 30px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius-top: 10;
  border-color: black transparent;
}
```

I tried using border-radius, but it did not yeild the desired effect

Comment: This page doesn't have the shape you're looking for, but it might help you learn a few tricks that could help: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @Flynn1179 - The moon trick was really cool, thanks for the link.

Comment: I have no idea how that helped you, but I'm glad it did :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this - http://codepen.io/AndrewSepic/pen/EKJxqM

```
#tv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50% / 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
#tv:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}
```

You could add another element to protrude from the TV shape to create the talk bubble effect.  For more ideas on what you can & can't do, I'd go [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/).

Comment: The question was on how to create the bubble effect, as you can see from the question I already have the box, as-well as an attachment. The issue is shaping the attachment. The link you provided was already provided in the comments and did not help

Comment: @Hobbyist your message bubbles were not visually clear to me.  But If I understand correctly you're going to need to make 2 shapes and put them together, to create what you're looking for.  Good luck!